# Algorithm to Find Corresponding Points Between two Images - OpenCV 3 Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.1

Working with OpenCV 3 and Python 3, I have two images depicting the same object, photographed from two different angles. In the first image I have found some test points and I want to find the corresponding ones in the other.

I have used a brute force matcher but in order to find the keypoints and the descriptors required, the only way was to use an ORB detector. It worked quite well but I want to find some specific points in the two images not some random or the best.

What algorithm can I use to do that?

Comment: show images of the point you want to detect... Do you know the position of one of the points a priori and you want to find the same point in the other image? Did you manually choose the test points? I think this is very hard in general. One approach could be to 1. compute ORB keypoints 2. choose the ORB keypoints around the target point in the first image and match them to the 2nd image 3. compute the homography between the images 4. transform the target point position with the homography - there are a few assumptions but it might work.

Comment: @Micka I know the points in the first image a priori and I want to detect them in the second, what I don't know is what algorithm is suitable.

Comment: the problem is, that there are too many freedoms in transformation. You can simply describe the target point by ORB/SIFT/SURF etc. but you won't know the "scale" and the "orientation" of the point, so you won't be able to find it efficiently in the other image. Similar problems occur for other neighboorhood-descriptions (color histograms etc.). If this problem was simple, no one would need ORB or SIFT/SURF at all. However, IF your target point has some known special properties, like a color marker (special color) or a QR code, then the problem can be solved much easier.

Comment: You could try building ranges for the (R, G, B) colors represented in the images. Say, if one pixel is between a certain "color range" (e.g. certain shares of green), then count it as "green." This method could function as a sort of dimensionality reduction.

Comment: In a similar vein, you could try comparing each pixel (assuming the photos are of the same dimension and the object is placed in the same spot in each photo) by comparing the pixel's RGD value to a range of RGB values. If the pixel in image 1 at point (5, 10) is within a certain range, RGB-value-wise, of the pixel in image 2 at point (5, 10), call them equal, or something.

Comment: @not_a_robot I have to use an already implemented algorithm. I am testing some things I read in a book and this part was supposed to be the easy one as having found the test points the book simply says just use an algorithm and find the corresponding ones. It is supposed to be child's play...

Comment: Would you mind sharing some more context around the problem, e.g. the book you're reading and the exercise exactly? If you had a large enough body of images, you could try running a neural net to classify the images. But it doesn't sound like this exercise is asking for a somewhat-deep learning solution like that.

Comment: @not_a_robot Nothing so complex! It is an introductory book on OpenCV. I just try to use the algorithms on 2 simple gray images. There is not a specific exercise. It just says that if you wish to find the corresponding points just use one of the implemented algorithms and that is why it doesn't explain anything else...